# Many errors occurred after the error "the connection was dropped by the other side"

Tags: asp.net, postgresql

There are a lot of the following errors in the log:

```
14:05:58.827 ERROR:     DISCARD ALL cannot be executed inside a transaction block
14:05:58.827 OPERATOR:  DISCARD ALL
14:05:58.827 ERROR:     current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
14:05:58.827 OPERATOR:  BEGIN
14:05:58.827 ERROR:     current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
14:05:58.827 OPERATOR:  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
14:05:58.827 ERROR:     current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

In the application that worked with this database, some functionality did not work partially. All this went on for half an hour. There are no direct calls to "DISCARD ALL", "BEGIN", or "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED" in the code. Access to the server is closed, there is only a log. Trying to figure out what it was, have any ideas?

Comment: If an error occurs in PostgreSQL during script execution, the transaction status will change to "aborted". The whole problem is that in order to restore the state, you need to call Rollback or Commit. This connection remains active in the connection pool and continues to accept requests. Each call results in a "current transaction is aborted" error. It is strange, but there is no way to solve this problem other than to fix the error and call the Rollback command. I will be glad if someone can help me with this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a broken connection pooler.  All of those commands could be issued by a connection pooler automatically when they check connections in or out.  So a seems like connection got broken, but the pooler blithely kept trying to hand it out anyway.  On the other hand, once it does hand out the connection something should happen on it which would cause yet more log messages, which doesn't seem to be happening, so maybe it keeps trying to 'revive' the connection, unsuccessfully.

But access to the server is not closed.  Many of those errors are coming from the server, so there must still be a connection to the server.  (You put "the connection was dropped by the other side" in the title, but that phrase is not included in any of the log you showed us so I don't know where you are getting it from.)  But the connection is in an aborted transaction, and is waiting for you to issue a `rollback;` or a `commit;` before it becomes usable again.

Comment: Maybe you can help in what exactly the pool was out of order? In an NpgSql module written for C#? Or in the connection pool of PostgreSQL itself? Is there any way to define it?

Comment: I've expanded my answer in general, but I don't know anything specific about Npgsql or any of its built-in poolers.  If you are using an external pooler (like pgbouncer for example)  please let us know what one you are using and how it is configured.